# Using IN outside CASE Statement after WHERE Clause i get SQL Error [1427] [21000]: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle

I have below query whereby i want to select all records at a specific hour but the other hours i want to filter to whitelisted records

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MY_TABLE
WHERE
    COLUMN_A IN
    (CASE
        WHEN TO_CHAR(COL_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDDHH24') != '2021111217' THEN (
            SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A
        FROM
            ANOTHER_TABLE )
        ELSE COLUMN_A 
    END);
```

However with the query i get error

> SQL Error [1427] [21000]: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more
> than one row

How do i write this query without using  union

Comment: What is "where column_a in column_a" supposed to mean?

Comment: column_a in column_a will select all the records

Comment: Why don’t you want to use union? It will probably be faster (unless you write it as an OR and Oracle uses OR Expansion to treat it as a union anyway)

Comment: `Union all` could be faster `union` is the slowest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   MY_TABLE
WHERE  (TO_CHAR(COL_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDDHH24') != '2021111217'
        AND COLUMN_A IN (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A FROM ANOTHER_TABLE))
OR     TO_CHAR(COL_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDDHH24') = '2021111217'
OR     col_timestamp IS NULL;
```

*The `IS NULL` filter is necessary as `!=` does not return false for `NULL != '2021111217'` so to match your original logic you need to include the extra filter.*

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it to

```
select * 
from my_table a
where a.column_a in 
  (select case when to_char(a.col_timestamp, 'yyyymmddhh24') <> '2021111217' then b.column_a
               else a.column_a
          end
     from another_table b
   )
```

---

As MT0 commented, that won't really work if `another_table` is empty, but this should:

```
select * 
from my_table a
where a.column_a in 
  (select b.column_a
     from another_table b
     where to_char(a.col_timestamp, 'yyyymmddhh24') <> '2021111217'
   union
   select a.column_a 
     from dual
     where to_char(a.col_timestamp, 'yyyymmddhh24') =  '2021111217'
        or a.col_timestamp is null
   );
```

Comment: This will not match any rows if `ANOTHER_TABLE` is empty.

Comment: Right; thank you, @MT0. Suggested another option (in case that table really is empty).

Comment: The second one won't match when `a.col_timestamp` is `null`; you need to include an `OR a.col_timestamp IS NULL` check in the second sub-query.

Comment: So true, @MT0; thanks again.